# Rails simple_format not handling some strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use Rails' `simple_format()` method, but it isn't working as examples online seem to indicate: It works on a double quoted string, but not a single quoted string, and it also doesn't work on text fields in models returned from my DB.

```ruby
simple_format "Hello\n\nWorld"
# Hello
# World

simple_format 'Hello\n\nWorld'
# Hello\n\nWorld

simple_format @model.hello_world
# Hello\n\nWorld

simple_format "#{@model.hello_world}"
# Hello\n\nWorld
```

Why does the method treat these string differently? I haven't seen anything in the examples or docs stating that this behavior is expected, specifically with strings provided from model fields. How can I display my dynamic content with formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby treats single quotes and double quotes differently. [Documentation on Strings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes)

In single quoted strings only backslashes and apostrophes are escaped (supported). This is why `"#{variable}"` works in Rails but `'#{variable}'` doesn't. If you need to escape something (variable, newline, etc.), use double quotes.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear in the question, let me rephrase: I know the difference between the two strong syntaxes. What I am asking is why `simple_format()` treats these differently, since there is no mention in the documentation of this. It says it converts parts of a string separated by the literal `\n\n` into HTML paragraphs, but this appears to only be true for double quoted string literals. I don't really care about the behavior on single quoted string literals, but the real problem is that I have model fields to display it won't handle. How do I rectify this?

Comment: See alternate answer, it turns out it was an issue with the source data that `simple_format()` was obscuring from me. The `\n\n` I was seeing was already formatted from the `\\n\\n` stored accidentally to the db.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the data coming from the database content: If the database content is loaded from a single-quoted string (in my case buried in my seeds), it is escaped when it is stored in the database. The content I had in the db was actually:

> Hello\n\nWorld

This is sent to simple_format as "escaped-slash, n, escaped-slash, n", which is rendered properly:

> Hello\n\nWorld

If simple format isn't working for you with db content, check your content!